# Catching an error in HttpGet in AsyncTask on Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-get

I've got an `AsyncTask` working which does an `HttpGet`. It works fine when the HTML text file is found, but when HTML file is not found, I want to display something in a `TextView`. Now, displaying the text when the HTML is not found works fine on my phone which is Android 2.3.4, but on my tablet, (Android 4.4.4) it's like the `onPostExecute` never happens because the `ProgressDialog` is never dismissed, and the text is not displayed in the TextView. Any ideas on what the problem here is? The `AsyncTask`:

```
private class GetURLData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private String HTMLStr;
    private String Error = null;
    private ProgressDialog htmlDialog = new ProgressDialog(
            MyActivity.this);

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        htmlDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        htmlDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            HTMLStr = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        htmlDialog.dismiss();

        if (Error != null) {

            HTML_TV.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + titleStr
                    + "</b> <br>" + bodyStr));


        } else {
            Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(HTMLStr,
                    MyActivity.this, null);
            HTML_TV.setText(spanned);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't the solution but I just wanted to point out that `Error = e.getMessage();` looks like you have no variable name to assign `e.getMessage()` to. Unless `Error` is your variable name, in which case you should use all lower case letters as is the convention.

Comment: There is no point to call cancel(true) in doInBackground since you expect onPostExecute() being called no matter what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `cancel(true);` when you catch an exception in your doInBackground method. It means, that **onPostExecute will not be called** then.

See cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)'s documentation, which says *"Calling this method guarantees that onPostExecute(Object) is never invoked."*:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)

I think you should fill your `onCancelled(Result result)` method too or you should not use the cancel() method at all.

Comment: yup, cancel(true); was the culprit! Thanks everyone.